# Need help in generating a certain pattern of hashes

Tags: c++

I have been trying to generate a pattern of hashes that looks something like this:

```
#            #
 ##        ##
  ###    ###
   ########
```

My code is :-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int pro = 1;
int space2= 12;
int handle = space2;
int space = 3;
int handle2 = space;

for (int i = 2 ; i <=8 ; i = i+2)
{

    space = handle2;
    handle = space2;


    int k = i;
    while (k > 0)
    {
        if (k == i/2)
        {

            while (space2 > 0)
            {
                cout << " ";
                space2--;

            }

            cout << "#";
            k--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i > 2){
                while (space <=3){
                    cout << " ";
                    space ++;
                }
                handle2 --;
            }
            cout << "#";
            k--;
        }

    }
    space2 = handle - 4;
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that i have done some stupid mistake but i can't seem to find out . The pattern generated by this code has the hashes correct but its messed up in the spaces. Can anyone just tell me where i have gone wrong? Just the error, i'll figure how to correct it on my own. Thanks!

OUTPUT:-

```
#            #
 ##        ##
    ###    ###
         ########
```

Comment: What's the output you have ?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: I pressed debug button but there was no error. Apart from that i don't know anything more . I'm a beginner.

Comment: Then I recommend you a bit of reading about [How to debug *step by step*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+to+debug+step+by+step&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=5Z29VqDbLcyIaODaktgH), it will help you for the rest of your programming life

Comment: Okay thank you i'll have a look into it .

Comment: After that, if you don't succeed, post your attempts and ping me for more help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that lets you solve your problem with a much shorter program: decompose your pattern into parts, and describe their sizes in terms of row number.

First thing to note is that your pattern is symmetrical: its right side is the mirror image of its left side. Splitting the pattern in half gives you your next observation: the halves are seven-character wide:

```
#      |      #
 ##    |    ##
  ###  |  ###
   ####|####

1234567 7654321
```

Left side of each row consists of a prefix of `p` spaces, a run of octothorps of length `h`, and a suffix of `s` spaces. Prefix `p` and suffix `s` could have zero length. Right side is composed of suffix followed by the run of octothorps; prefix is whitespace, so it could be omitted.

Now let's figure out the values of `p`, `h`, and `s` for each row. Assume that rows are numbered from zero (because things in C++ are generally numbered from zero):

- `p` is zero for the initial row, one for the next row, two for the next row, and so on. Hence, `p` is equal to the `row` number.
- `h` is one for the initial row, two for the next row, and so on. Hence, `h` is `row+1`.
- `s` is always `7-p-h`, making it `7-row-(row+1)`, i.e. `6-2*row`.

With these observations in place, all you need to do is to write a function that prints `n` characters, and call it repeatedly from your loop, passing the character and the count:

```
void printRepeatedCharacter(char c, int n); // Implement this
```

Your loop would look like this:

```
for (int row = 0 ; row != 4 ; row++) {
    printRepeatedCharacter(' ', row);     // prefix
    printRepeatedCharacter('#', row+1);   // #-s, left part
    printRepeatedCharacter(' ', 6-2*row); // suffix, left part
    printRepeatedCharacter(' ', 6-2*row); // suffix, right part
    printRepeatedCharacter('#', row+1);   // #-s, right part
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Amazing explanation . Thank you. I never thought of patterns this way.

Comment: _"s is always 7-p-s"_ huh?

Comment: @PreferenceBean You are right, it's h, not s. Thank you for the edit and for catching this.

Comment: nppzzzzzzz​​​​​ (wasn't confident enough to fix that one though I did suspect you meant _h_)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems a bit convoluted, but let's analyse what you are trying to do. You want to generate a pattern like this:

```
#------ ------#
-##---- ----##-
--###-- --###--
---#### ####---
```

It's symmetrical down the middle (where I left a space), and the other lines follow a regular pattern, which can be described by the following numbers (from left to right: number of spaces, number of hashes, number of spaces. This is just the left side, the right side is the same pattern reversed):

```
0 1 6
1 2 4
2 3 2
3 4 0
```

The best way to generate such a pattern is to come up with functions that generates those numbers. Let's try:

```
int main () {
    const int NumIterations = 4;

    for (int x=0; x<NumIterations; ++x) {
        // print 'x' spaces
        // print 'x+1' hashes
        // print '(NumIterations - x - 1) * 2' spaces

        // print '(NumIterations - x - 1) * 2' spaces
        // print 'x+1' hashes
        // print 'x' spaces
    }
}
```

Let's add a print function:

```
void print (char c, int count) {
    for (int x=0; x<count; ++x)
         cout << c;
}
```

Now our main function can become this:

```
int main () {
    const int NumIterations = 4;

    for (int x=0; x<NumIterations; ++x) {
        print (' ', x);
        print ('#', x+1);
        print (' ', (NumIterations - x - 1) * 2);
        print (' ', (NumIterations - x - 1) * 2);
        print ('#', x+1);
        print (' ', x);
    }
}
```

Of course you can optimize this further by combining the middle two print statements, and you might want to leave out the final print statement:

```
int main () {
    const int NumIterations = 4;

    for (int x=0; x<NumIterations; ++x) {
        print (' ', x);
        print ('#', x+1);
        print (' ', (NumIterations - x - 1) * 4);
        print ('#', x+1);
    }
}
```

And that's it. Hope this helps!